# Subtract elements of sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
Helix_clear[0] = [['39', '45'], ['2', '3'], ..., ['100', '150']]
```

I would like to get this result:

```
Helix_clear[0] = [6, 1, ..., 50]
```

I need to come with a function to subtract all the elements in every sublist to come up with a list with the result of that operation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to do this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, what you need to do is writing a loop accessing all elements which are also lists within your list, then subtracting elements of your sub-lists. Your list elements are strings and you need to convert them into integers to be able to subtract. You can use something like this;

```
Helix_clear[0] = [int(i[1]) - int(i[0]) for i in Helix_clear[0]]
```

However, if your sub-lists contain more than two elements at some point, you'd require a more complex answer.

If you'd like to use this as a function, you might use something like this;

```
def subtractFunc(listy_thing):
    return [int(i[1]) - int(i[0]) for i in listy_thing]

Helix_clear[0] = subtractFunc(Helix_clear[0])
```

Comment: I don't think you need `abs`, it looks like the OP just wants `int(i[1]) - int(i[0])`

Comment: I tried something like that but didint work. I will try that. But my biggest problem was to integrate that into a function so that i could do that for the other 1000 list. And I only have 2 elements per sublist

Comment: When I tried to do do it my self and used something like that didint work. I now I know why. My Helix_clear has multiple lists, for example:
print(Helix_clear)
[['1', '2'], ['3','4'], ...]
[['1', '2'], ['3','4'], ...]
[['1', '2'], ['3','4'], ...]

With that function it doesnt expecify anything and says I cant interger a list.
Sorry for not knowing how to write in code...
@UtkuTombul

Answer (score 0):

```
Helix_clear = [ int(ll[1])- int(ll[0]) for ll in Helix_clear ]
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your code.